# Adding multiple arrays to fputcsv

Tags: php, fputcsv

I have the following code that is creating a csv from the array `$allsubs`, I also have another array called `$allpaused`, how can I add this onto the csv?

E.g So it runs through adding everything within `$allsubs` then at the bottom of that adds all from `$allpaused`.

```
   $csvName = "file.csv";
    $fileHandle = fopen($csvName, 'w') or die('Can\'t create .csv file, try again later.');

    //Add the headers
    fputcsv($fileHandle, $headers);

    //Add the data
    foreach ($allsubs as $item) {
        fputcsv($fileHandle, $item);
    }

    //close file
    fclose($fileHandle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Surely this would work?**

```
$csvName = "file.csv";
$fileHandle = fopen($csvName, 'w') or die('Can\'t create .csv file, try again later.');

//Add the headers
fputcsv($fileHandle, $headers);

//Add the data
foreach ($allsubs as $item) {
    fputcsv($fileHandle, $item);
}

//Add the data
foreach ($allpaused as $item) {
    fputcsv($fileHandle, $item);
}

//close file
fclose($fileHandle);
```

I have added a foreach of the `$allpaused` array, I haven't tested this but logically it makes sense. If you can let me know if this work that would be great.

Comment: I should've just tried that myself, it did cross my mind, ha! Oh well it works, thanks.